# Is there any performance difference in toArray vs stream.toArray in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, java-8, java-stream

I need to convert a list of ids to array of ids.
I can do it in many ways but not sure which one should be used.

Say,

```
1. ids.stream().toArray(Id[]::new)
2. ids.toArray(new Id[ids.length])
```

Which one is more efficient and why?

Comment: Unless you actually want to use the stream API, I can't think of a good reason to use the first approach. I can't imagine the performance difference would justify the decreased readability of the code.

Comment: Do you _really_ have performance issues? How many lists are we talking about? Can't that conversion be avoided in the first place?

Comment: First : What do you mean by efficient ? less memory use, less CPU use, fastest ? Second : Is your array big enough to really make a difference ? If no, use the more readable, not the more efficient.

Comment: Efficient means execution speed is faster. The array may contain 6 million entries

Comment: @vincrichaud not everything that is obvious turns to be faster, for example : `ids.toArray(new Id[ids.length])` will be slower then `ids.toArray(new Id[0])`

Comment: @Eugene that's not what I said, as I agree with you, the more readable is not he fastest. What I mean is you should prioritize what you are coding. If we talk about an array of 20 entries, such optimization should not be considered, and we should use the more readable. If (as OP) you use millions of data, then optimization become interesting and may take the lead on the readability (that where commenting code become useful)

Comment: @vincrichaud right, the OP said 6 million though

Comment: `ids.toArray(new Id[ids.length])` won’t compile. You meant `ids.toArray(new Id[ids.size()])`, but as @Eugene already mentioned, that won’t be better than `ids.toArray(new Id[0])`…

Answer (score 6):

java-11 introduced `Collection::toArray` that has this implementation:

```
default <T> T[] toArray(IntFunction<T[]> generator) {
    return toArray(generator.apply(0));
}
```

To make it simpler in your case, it is actually doing : `ids.toArray(new Id[0])`; that is - it is not specifying the total expected size.

This is faster than specifying the size and it's non-intuitive; but has to do with the fact that if the JVM can prove that the array that you are allocating is going to be overridden by some copying that is immediately followed, it does not have to do the initial zeroing of the array and that proves to be faster then specifying the initial size (where the zeroing has to happen).

The stream approach will have (or try to guess an estimate) an initial size that the stream internals will compute, because:

```
 ids.stream().toArray(Id[]::new)
```

is actually:

```
 ids.stream().toArray(size -> Id[size]);
```

and that `size` is either known or estimated, based on the internal characteristics that a `Spliterator` has. If the stream reports `SIZED` characteristic (like in your simple case), then it's easy, `size` is always known. On the other hand if this `SIZED` is not present, stream internals will only have an estimate of how many elements will be present and in such a case, an hidden new collection will be used to capture elements, called `SpinedBuffer`.

You can read more [here](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/), but the approach `ids.toArray(new Id[0])` will be the fastest.

Comment: Not every `Collection` produces a `SIZED` stream, i.e. concurrent collections won’t. But for concurrent collections,  `ids.toArray(new Id[ids.size()])` would be even broken unless the application can preclude concurrent modifications during the operation. So it boils down to `ids.toArray(new Id[0])` being the simplest, least error-prone, *and* most efficient solution.